# Let $f:X\to Y$ closed and continuous and let $G$ be the graph of f. Then the projections $\pi_X:G\to X$ and $\pi_Y:G\to Y$ are closed.

Tags: general-topology

I'm solving some problems for self studying. I'm stuck in this exercise:

Let $f:X\to Y$ and consider $G:=\{(x,f(x))\mid x\in X\}$ the graph of $f$ as a subspace of $X\times Y$ with the product topology. If $f$ is closed and continuous, then the projections $\pi_X:G\to X$ and $\pi_Y:G\to Y$ are closed.

Here's what I did:

Let $K$ be a closed set of $G$. We would like to prove that $\pi_X(K)$ is a closed subset of $X$.

As $K$ is closed in $G$, then $(G-K)$ is an open subset of $G$, and because que are considering $G$ as a subspace of $X\times Y$, then we can write $X-G=(U_x\times U_Y)\cap G$ where $U_X$ is an open set of $X$ and $U_Y$ is on open set of $Y$.

I don't know how to continue. I haven't used any of the hypothesis but It's not clear how to.

Any hint is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
h : & X & \longrightarrow & G = \Gamma(f) \\
    & x & \longmapsto & (x,f(x)) \end{array}$$ is an homeomorphism if $f$ is continuous. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535466/is-the-graph-of-a-continuous-function-homeomorphic-to-its-domain) for the proof.

$\pi_X$ the inverse of $h$ is therefore closed. *We don't need the hypothesis $f$ closed to prove that $\pi_X$ is closed.*

Regarding $\pi_Y$, we have $\pi_Y = f \circ h^{-1}$ which is closed as a composition of two closed maps if $f$ is also supposed to be closed.