# Can the graph of a continuous real function be a totally disconnected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, graphing-functions, connectedness

Can the graph of a continuous real function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a totally disconnected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Certainly there can be many disconnected points (in $\mathbb{R}^2$), like the point $(0,0)$ in the graph of:

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 x\sin\frac{1}{x}&\text{if}\, x\neq 0\\
 0&\text{if}\, x=0\\
\end{cases}
$

And perhaps it isn't necessary for the graph of $f$ to be connected either side of these "disconnected points".

Whether or not there is a real function $f$ and dense subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}$ so that $\{\ (x,f(x)): x\in X\}$ is a totally disconnected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2,\ $ I am not sure. Perhaps this is not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph of any continuous function $f:X\to Y$ is homeomorphic to $X$ via $x\mapsto \big(x,f(x)\big)$ ([see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535466/is-the-graph-of-a-continuous-function-homeomorphic-to-its-domain)). In particular any continuous function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ has a (path)connected graph.

It is unclear why you think that your particular $f$ has a disconnected graph. It certainly is even path connected.