# Are the sets $\Bbb R^+\times\{0\}$ and $\mathcal G(f):=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:xy=1\wedge x\in\Bbb R^+\}$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples

So I would like to prove that the sets $\Bbb R^+\times\{0\}$ and $\mathcal G(f):=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:xy=1\wedge x\in\Bbb R^+\}$ are homemorphic and to do this I tried to use the following argumentations.

> It is a well know result that the graph $\mathcal G$ of a continuous function is homeomorphic to its domain: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535466/is-the-graph-of-a-continuous-function-homeomorphic-to-its-domain) for details. Now, let be $f:\Bbb R^+\rightarrow\Bbb R$ the function
> $$
> f(x):=\frac 1 x
> $$
> for any $x\in\Bbb R^+$ so that we know that the sets $\Bbb R^+$ and $\mathcal G(f)$ are homeomorphic. Now $\Bbb R^+$ is homeomorphic via the natural immersion to the set $\Bbb R^+\times\{0\}$ so that the sets $\Bbb R^+\times\{0\}$ and $\mathcal G(f)$ are homeomorphic but the first is not closed whereas the second is closed because the origin is an accumulation point for $\Bbb R^+\times\{0\}$ and it is not there contained so that this set cannot be closed, whereas $\mathcal G(f)$ is the zero set of the continuous function $g:\Bbb R^2\rightarrow\Bbb R$ defined though the equation
> $$
> g(x,y):=xy-1
> $$
> for any $x,y\in\Bbb R^+$ and thus by continuity $\mathcal G(f)$ is closed

So [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4432908/736008) @SassatelliGiulio objected that the argumentations I gave are incorrect stating that

> *the closed graph theorem will only carry you up to proving that $\mathcal G(f)$ is closed in $\Bbb R^+×R$, which doesn't tell much about whether or not it's closed in $\Bbb R^2$*

but unfortunately then he did not give me any clarifications about some questions I posed to him and thus I thought to put a specific question where I ask clarifications because to me is very important to understand my mistakes. So first of all the graph theorem I mentioned does not say to me that $\mathcal G(f)$ is closed to the point that I proved it with appropriate argumentations; I point out that I know perfectly that $\Bbb R^+\times\{0\}$ is not a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ but it is surely true that it is homeomorphic to a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ whose elements have the second coordinate zero just like I know that even though the graph theorem states that $\Bbb R^+$ is homeomorphic to a subset of $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ then this is not surely a problem because via the natural bjiection this last set is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$ so that $\mathcal G(f)$ is homeomorphic to a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ which has the same properties. Moreover I would like to know if the argumetations I gave can be used to show that $(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})\times\{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:xy=1\}$. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Part of the issue, here and in the linked questions, is you're speaking of "open" and "closed" as if they're properties of a set rather than properties of _subsets of a metric space_.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I do not speak very well English so excuse me for bad writing. So I will to try to clarify: originally I asked to prove or disprove that a closed or open set E of a topological space X can be homeomorphic to another set $F$ of $X$hat is not closed or open, that's all.

Comment: So if the argumentations I gave are correct then I proved that a closed subset of $\Bbb R^2$, that is $\mathcal G(f)$, is homeomorphic to a subset, that is $\Bbb R^+\times\{0\}$ of the same space which is not closed and not open. So can you say now if my counterexample with the argumentations work? Forgive my bad English.

Comment: Your English is quite good. :) (Certainly orders of magnitude better than my Italian!) <> To your question, yes: If $(X, T)$ is a topological space, there can exist two homeomorphic subsets $E_1$ and $E_2$ with one closed in $(X, T)$ and the other not; or with one open and the other not. <> As subsets of the real line, $(0, 1)$ (not closed) is homeomorphic to $(-\infty, \infty)$; as subsets of $(0, 3)$ with the Euclidean topology, $(0,1]$ (closed) is homeomorphic to $(1, 2]$ (not closed).

Comment: Your example is good: The set $xy=1$ and $x > 0$ (closed in the Euclidean plane) is homeomorphic to $(0, \infty) \times \{0\}$ (neither open nor closed in the Euclidean plane).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Okay, thanks very much for clarifications!!! <> Moreover thanks for your encouragement about my English: indeed, I am afraid that it is quite difficult to understand because I use latin phrase model to write but unfortunately Latin and English are not so similar...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly proved that $\Bbb R^+\times\{0\}$ and $\mathcal G(f)=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:xy=1\wedge x\in\Bbb R^+\}$ are homeomorphic.

Nevertheless SassatelliGiulio is right when he says that you *did not prove* that $\mathcal G(f)$ is closed in $\mathbb R^2$:

Your map $g$ is continuous, hence $g^{-1}(0)$ is closed - **but** $\mathcal G(f) \ne g^{-1}(0)$.

However, it is easy to fix your argument. The set $Z = [0,\infty) \times \mathbb R$ is closed in $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathcal G(f) = g^{-1}(0) \cap Z$. Thus $\mathcal G(f)$ is closed.

Comment: Okay, all clear now: thanks very much for your assistance!